# UITableView not scrolling to last row after inserting a new row

Tags: ios6, uiscrollview, uikit, uitableview

I am trying to insert rows in the TableViewController's tableView Object from other class using

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    ReceiptHomeTableViewController *homeTableViewController= (ReceiptHomeTableViewController*)navigationController.viewControllers[0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([[PersistenceService getInstance] count]-1) inSection:0];
    [homeTableViewController.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

I have also tried using

```
//[homeTableViewController.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
//[homeTableViewController.tableView reloadData];
```

but the HometableViewContoller only shows the rows that fit in the screen width. I try to scroll to bottom, but it don't go to last row. 
Scrolling works perfect if I restart the application and cells are created using ellForRowAtIndexPath: method, but fails to work if I add new rows.

It seems like UI is not updated about the new length of the View when a row is added. Any help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem. I had autolayout turned on by default on tableviewcontroller. turning it off worked for me.

Thanks for the sihhestions

Answer (score 1):

Due to below 50 reputation, i won't able to give comments. So i like to give suggestion about this question in answer section.

From your question, you must post `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Then only clue will click. And please `NSLog` your new row objects in the view where the tableCell sub viewed.

After you edit your post, I'll give answer in this post by edit if i got answer or any clue.

Comment: hi now you should be able to comment `;)`